# Pass JQuery datepicker value to control action using @Url.Action

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to pass asp.net mvc view date time value to mvc controller. but it getting null value.

**Chtml Code**

```
<input type="date" id="start_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Check in" data-ng-model="departuredate" />
<input type="date" id="end_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Check Out" data-ng-model="returndate" />
<a class="link_button2" ng-href="@Url.Action("Booking", "home")?DepartureDate={{departuredate1}}&ReturnDate={{returndate}}"> Search </a>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    if (datefield.type != "date") { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        jQuery(function ($) { //on document.ready
            $('#start_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date2 = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    $("input[name='something']").val(date2);
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                    $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                    //sets minDate to start_date date + 1
                    $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);

                }
            });
            $('#end_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onClose: function () {
                    var start_date = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    console.log(start_date);
                    var end_date = $('#end_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    if (end_date <= start_date) {
                        var minDate = $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    }



</script>
```

**ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Booking(string DepartureDate, string ReturnDate){}
```

When press search button get null value to action result. I want to know what is wrong with this code.?

Comment: do you see date in url?

Comment: no i can't debug in that point. url is working . after press search actionresult get null value. but i remove JQueryUI from page , its working.

Comment: I think problem is JQueryUI. what wrong with that?

Comment: does your url looks like this ? `home/Booking?DepartureDate=17-09-09 &ReturnDate=17-09-09`

Comment: no. its like `home/Booking?DepartureDate=2017-06-24T18:30:00.000Z&ReturnDate=2017-06-24T18:30:00.000Z`

Comment: But it's only working after remove **JQueryUI** . Otherwise it's getting null

Answer (score 0):

Dates are not appending properly in URL as date-format given in date picker 'yy-mm-dd' because it also appends time. Try to convert it manually in javascript and post it for just testing purpose to know whether issue is in JqueryUi Date picker.